# Spark SQL queries on Partitioned Data

Tags: apache-spark

I have setup a Spark 1.3.1 application that collects event data.  One of the attributes is a timestamp called 'occurredAt'.   Im intending to partition the event data into parquet files on a filestore and in accordance with the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery) it indicates that time based values are not supported only string and int,  so i've split the date into Year, Month, Day values and partitioned as follows

```
events
  |---occurredAtYear=2015
  |   |---occurredAtMonth=07
  |   |   |---occurredAtDay=16
  |   |   |   |---<parquet-files>
  ...
```

I then load the parquet file from the root path /events

```
sqlContext.parquetFile('/var/tmp/events')
```

Documentation says:

> 'Spark SQL will automatically extract the partitioning information
>   from the paths'

However my query

```
SELECT * FROM events where occurredAtYear=2015
```

Fails miserably saying spark cannot resolve 'occurredAtYear'

I can see the schema for all other aspects of the event and can do queries on those attributes, but printSchema does not list occurredAtYear/Month/Day on the schema at all?  What am I missing to get partitioning working appropriately.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it turns out I was following the instructions too precisely, I was actually writing the parquet files out to

```
/var/tmp/occurredAtYear=2015/occurredAtMonth=07/occurredAtDay=16/data.parquet
```

The 'data.parquet' was additionally creating a further directory with parquet files underneath,  I should have been saving the parquet file to

```
/var/tmp/occurredAtYear=2015/occurredAtMonth=07/occurredAtDay=16
```

All works now with the schema being discovered correctly.

Comment: Hi @vcetinick.. How do you partitioned the parquet file. Please help me in this

Comment: Parquet files themselves are not partitioned per-se.  The folder structure infers the partitioning.  So in the above case, the folder 'occuredAtMonth=07' is automatically inferred to be a column ontop of the columns that exist in the parquet files.